# add column to the scraped tables

Tags: python, web-scraping, data-science

i trying to add column that contains unique dates for every scraped tables from the weather website https://www.wunderground.com/history/daily/us/dc/washington/KDCA

i started with this code

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/razanalthawwadi/Desktop/chromedriver')
link='https://www.wunderground.com/history/daily/us/va/arlington- 
county/KDCA/Date/'

def list_dates(start,end):
""" This creates a list of of dates between the 'start' date and the 'end' date """
# create datetime object for the start and end dates
start = datetime.datetime.strptime(start, '%Y-%m-%d')
end = datetime.datetime.strptime(end, '%Y-%m-%d')
# generates list of dates between start and end dates
step = datetime.timedelta(days=1)
dates = []
while start <= end:
    dates.append(start.date())
    start += step
# return the list of dates in string format
return [str(date) for date in dates]

    dates=list_dates('2017-01-01','2017-12-31')
    we=[]
   
    datess=[]
    for i in dates:
#     print(i)
    datess.append(i)
    page=str(str(link) + str(i))
    driver.get(page)
    time.sleep(3)
    html=driver.page_source
    df=pd.read_html(html)
    we.append(df[1])
```

i tried to use this loop but it print the same date for all tables

```
for i in dates:

    wel.insert(loc=0, column='jj', value=i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just assign i during loop as date column to dataframe.

Note: not tested with all urls. Also, wunderground used to have an API so maybe looking into that rather than incurring the overhead of a browser.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/razanalthawwadi/Desktop/chromedriver')
link='https://www.wunderground.com/history/daily/us/va/arlington-county/KDCA/Date/'

def list_dates(start,end):
    """ This creates a list of of dates between the 'start' date and the 'end' date """
    # create datetime object for the start and end dates
    start = datetime.datetime.strptime(start, '%Y-%m-%d')
    end = datetime.datetime.strptime(end, '%Y-%m-%d')
    # generates list of dates between start and end dates
    step = datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    dates = []
    
    while start <= end:
        dates.append(start.date())
        start += step
    # return the list of dates in string format
    return [str(date) for date in dates]

dates = list_dates('2017-01-01','2017-12-31')
 
for i in dates:
    page= f'https://www.wunderground.com/history/daily/us/va/arlington-county/KDCA/Date/{i}'
    driver.get(page)
    # time.sleep(3)
    html = driver.page_source
    df= pd.read_html(html)[1]
    df.dropna(axis=0, how= 'all',  inplace = True)
    df['date'] = i
```

Comment: when i apply this code i have this error message     
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: what is the value of `page` when that error occurs please? i.e. on which page does error occur

Answer (score 0):

add to the fisrt loop:

> ```
> df[1].insert(loc=0, column='Date', value=i)
> ```

it works.